# Windows Store App using C# - how to change TextBlock color in RGB?

Tags: c#, windows-8

I know this: 
`myRectangle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);`

how to do it in RGB combination color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Color.FromArgb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cce5h557.aspx) method.

Example:

```
Color red = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0);
SolidBrush  myBrush = new SolidBrush(red);
```

Then:

```
myRectangle.Fill = myBrush;
```

Comment: The linked documentation for Color.FromArgb is in the System.Drawing namespace which is not supported in Windows Store Apps... The Windows Store App [version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.color.aspx) of the Color structure can be found in Windows.UI. Also, the FromArgb method found on that class doesn't not have an overload that takes just the RGB values. You'll have to supply an alpha value as well. `Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
//Color.FromArgb(red,green,blue ) ;
Color blue=Color.FromArgb(0,0,255):
```

of course you can put other numbers to get your desired color